# Asynchronous RPROMPT? OR, faster git status for RPROMPT?

Tags: zsh, zshrc

Since I started using git I've had my RPROMPT setup to show the current branch. I've recently been using some of the "fancy" scripts to show un/staged file counts and other useful at a glance things. (https://github.com/olivierverdier/zsh-git-prompt/tree/master)

After using this for a week or two, its performance started to bother me.

Are there faster ways of getting this info or are there maybe ways to asynchronously write the RPROMPT? I don't want to wait to type a command while the RPROMPT is computed and would be perfectly happy with it popping in slightly later then my main PROMPT.

No offense to the aforementioned script; it's great. I'm just impatient.

Comment: Cross-posted at [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91087/asynchronous-rprompt).